# How to change hint_text's font name in KivyMD Textfield?

Tags: kivy, textfield, python-3.8, kivymd

I was programming with Kivymd, and I have a problem.

My KV code:

```
MDTextField:
    hint_text: "Hint Text"
    font_name: "Fontname.ttf"
```

When I change font_name of `MDTextfield`, font of field changes. But, hint text's font does not changes. It's font is still default font.

Is there any way to change hint text's font? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide relevant code, so we can help you. In addition, the most probable cause of this issue is that the config gets overwritten later in code.

Comment: The font for the `hint_text` is hard coded into the `MDTextField`. The authors have not provided any way to change it.

Comment: @JohnAnderson  Any way to change hard coded things?

Comment: Only by re-writing the code. You may be able to extend the MDTextField to create a custom MDTextField with the behavior that you want.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
MDTextField:
     hint_text: "Hint Text"
     font_name_hint_text:'Fontname.ttf'
```

Comment: could you provide some explanation on why this works?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value